# Running 4K @60Hz with a late-2014 MacBook Pro 13"?

Tags: macos, macbook, macbook-pro, macbook-pro-retina, 4k-resolution

Is there any chance to have 4K @60Hz with an external display with a late-2014 MacBook Pro 13"?

I know, Apple's official web site states that it's only supported by a newer generation: mid-215 MacBook Pro 13". It says it can do only 30Hz.

Even though, I am wondering if anybody managed to make it running, thanks to a special driver or software update, maybe a special display cable?

Screenshot: [About Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FiUo.png)

Screenshot: [Display Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyTJR.png)

Comment: This is likely a hardware limitation.  4K @60Hz would require a much faster signalling rate over the HDMI cable than 30Hz.

Answer (score 1):

A cable will not be able to achieve such an imporvement. The reason it is limited to 30Hz is because of hardware limitations.

A 13" Macbook Pro 2014 does not support 4k @ 60 Hz because of the CPU is a U-type processor.

> This type of resolution is supported on 4th generation Intel® Core™ processor family (Intel® Iris™ Pro Graphics 5200 / Intel® Iris™ Graphics 5100, Intel® HD Graphics 5000 / 4600 / 4400 / 4200)
>
> See the following supported screen resolutions through DP 1.2
>
> DisplayPort* 1.2 / eDP*
>
> H-Processors: 3840 x 2160@60Hz
>
> **U-Processors: 3200 x 2000 @60 Hz*, 3840x2160@30Hz**
>
> *Embedded display port.
>
> Please check additional information about graphics controller h

Here is some of the [processor information for MacBook Pro's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Third_generation_.28Retina.29)